# Getting the exact system time during program execution

Tags: python, alarm

I'm doing an alarm clock and I want to print alarm raise if the system time is the same as the one being save but it turn out that while running the program the time became static that's why it didn't raise the alarm while the program is still executed.
How can I make the time not to be static during program execution? Just let me know if you need additional information. :)

```
def alarmClock(self):
        timeString2 = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        getData = self.queryResultTable.get_children()
        

        for data in getData:
            
            for dataValue in self.queryResultTable.item(data)['values']: #sample data: 19:00:00 or 20:00:00
                
                for timeData in timeString2:
                
                    if  timeData == dataValue:
                        print('alarm Raise')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just check the time when you get to your conditional. This way it will check the time right before you are checking to see if an alarm should be raised. In my opinion this will be much simpler than having it run in the background the whole time. You don't need to make a new variable it would just look like this:

```
    if time.ctime() == dataValue:
         print("alarm Raise")
```